# Generate lists in which every sublist has a unique element

Tags: code-golf, array, integer, subsequence

The problem is defined as follows:

Create a function that takes an integer and returns a list of integers, with the following properties:

- Given a positive integer input, *n*, it produces a list containing *n* **integers ≥ 1.**
- Any *sublist* of the output must contain at least one unique element, which is different from all other elements from the same sublist. *Sublist* refers to a *contiguous* section of the original list; for example, `[1,2,3]` has sublists `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, `[1,2]`, `[2,3]`, and `[1,2,3]`.
- The list returned must be the lexicographically smallest list possible.

There is only one valid such list for every input. The first few are:

```
f(2) = [1,2]         2 numbers used
f(3) = [1,2,1]       2 numbers used
f(4) = [1,2,1,3]     3 numbers used
```

Comment: Wouldn't [1,2,1] be incorrect because elements 1 are the same?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're going to have to better define "lexicographically" better over the solution space.

Comment: e.g. why isn't `[0,1]` better than `[1,2]` for f(2)?

Comment: @Timtech: No, because the first 1 is in another sublist than the second 1. A sublist is a contiguous section of the original list, so there are three sublists: [1] [1,2] [1]

Comment: @McKay: Thanks for clarifying. I’ve added the constraint ≥ 1. (By the way, I didn’t post the problem; OP: I hope you’re OK with my edits)

Comment: @ProgramFOX Okay, I get it now.

Comment: Does 'lexicographically' mean 'with the lowest possible sum'?

Comment: @Oberon it means the natural sorting order. For example `[1, 1, 2]` < `[1, 2, 1]` when compared element by element.

Comment: shouldn't f(3) be [1,2] ([[1],[2],[1,2]]) and f(4) be [1,1,2] ([[1],[1],[2],[1,2]) ?

Comment: @ProgramFOX and everyone who voted to close this, since this question is tagged as code-golf I think we do have an objective winning criterion?

Comment: Ow, read that the list needs to answer list needs to be `n` long, that makes it even easier

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript (<strike>20</strike> 18 chars)

```
{,{.)^2base,}%}:f;
```

This is a simple binary ruler function, [A001511](http://oeis.org/A001511).

Equivalently

```
{,{).~)&2base,}%}:f;
{,{~.~)&2base,}%}:f;
{,{).(~&2base,}%}:f;
{,{{1&}{2/}/,)}%}:f;
```

Thanks for [primo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4098/primo) for saving 2 chars.

Comment: `).~)&` -> `.)^` for 2.

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 18

```
{+⌿~∨⍀⊖(⍵/2)⊤2×⍳⍵}
```

1 + number of trailing zeros in base 2 of each natural from 1 to N.

**Example**

```
      {+⌿~∨⍀⊖(⍵/2)⊤2×⍳⍵} 32
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.wiki/Sclipting), <s>26</s> 23 characters

```
감⓶上가增❷要❶감雙是가不감右⓶增⓶終終丟丟⓶丟終并
```

This piece of code generates a list of integers. However, if run as a program it will concatenate all the numbers together. As a stand-alone program, the following 25-character program outputs the numbers separated by commas:

```
감⓶上가增❷要감嚙是가不⓶增⓶終終丟丟⓶丟껀終合鎵
```

### Example output:

Input: `4`

Output: `1,2,1,3`

Input: `10`

Output: `1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ọ€2‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7t5HTWuMHjXM@P//v6EBAA)

### Explanation

```
ọ€2‘
 €      For each integer from 1 to {the command-line argument}
ọ         calculate the number of trailing zeroes in base
  2         2
   ‘    and increment {each resulting integer} {and output them}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7, 65 characters

```
print([len(bin(2*k).split('1')[-1]) for k in range(1,input()+1)])
```

The number of trailing zeros in 2, 4, 6, ..., 2n.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 40 characters

```
n&p=n:p++(n+1)&(p++n:p)
f n=take n$1&[]
```

Example runs:

```
λ: f 2
[1,2]
λ: f 3
[1,2,1]
λ: f 4
[1,2,1,3]
λ: f 10
[1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2]
λ: f 38
[1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õÈ¤q1 ÌÊÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9cikcTEgzMrE&input=NA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
(`take`t)
t=1:do x<-t;[x+1,1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyOhJDE7NaFEk6vE1tAqJV@hwka3xDq6QttQxzD2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqCodn/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)